# Sort Swift array of custom types

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, filter

I have an array of 5 custom objects (all objects are of the same custom type, `City`). The below is the output of typing `po cities` in my xcode terminal:

```
▿ 5 elements
  ▿ 0 : City
    ▿ name : Name
      - rawValue : "Manchester"
    ▿ description : Optional<String>
      - some : "Old Trafford"
  ▿ 1 : City
    ▿ name : Name
      - rawValue : "London"
    ▿ description : Optional<String>
      - some : "Emirates"
  ▿ 2 : City
    ▿ name : Name
      - rawValue : "Liverpool"
    ▿ description : Optional<String>
      - some : "Anfield"
  ▿ 3 : City
    ▿ name : Name
      - rawValue : "Newcastle"
    ▿ description : Optional<String>
      - some : "St James Park"
  ▿ 4 : City
    ▿ name : Name
      - rawValue : "Norwich"
    ▿ description : Optional<String>
      - some : "Carrow Road"
```

How can I sort these so the first three items returned from this array are **always** `London` ,  `Liverpool`, `Manchester`? The final 2 elements order is irrelevant here.

I've tried forcing the order of the elements by their current array position, i.e. forcing `City[0]` to move to `City[2]` - however this isn't suitable as the order I receive the elements within `City` can change - the position needs to be set based on the output of the specific `City` `rawValue`

TIA

Comment: You will need to implement Comparable for the objects in question.

Comment: It isn't clear what that sort order would be. Alphabetical by name would be Liverpool, London, Manchester. You want the order to be London , Liverpool, Manchester?

Comment: Correct - an alphabetical sort does not work as a result

Comment: So where does your desired result come from, logically?

Comment: It's a preference in terms of displaying what is associated with those elements to end users in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort your cities based on raw value:

```
let sortedCities = cities.sorted { $0.name.rawValue < $1.name.rawValue }
sortedCities.forEach {print($0)}
```

However, you say you want them sorted in the order London , Liverpool, Manchester, which is **not** alphabetical.

### Edit:

If you have some arbitrary sort order for your Name values, I suggest using a dictionary of sort indexes:

```
enum Name: String {
    case Manchester
    case London
    case Liverpool
    case Newcastle
    case Norwich
}

let sortIndexes: [Name: Int] = [.London:0,
                              .Liverpool:1,
                              .Manchester: 2,
                              .Newcastle: 3,
                              .Norwich: 4,
    ]

struct City: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: Name
    let info: String?
    var description: String {
        let info = self.info ?? "nil"
        return "City(name: \(self.name.rawValue), info: \(info))"
    }
}


let cities = [
    City(name: .London, info:  "Emirates"),
    City(name: .Liverpool, info:  "Anfield"),
    City(name: .Manchester, info:  "Old Trafford"),
    City(name: .Newcastle, info:  "St James Park"),
    City(name: .Norwich, info:  "Carrow Road"),
]

let sortedCities = cities.sorted { sortIndexes[$0.name]! < sortIndexes[$1.name]! }

sortedCities.forEach {print($0)}
```

Alternately, you can make your enums be type Int, and use a description to map to display names, as suggested in Leo's comment.

Here is working example code for that approach:

```
enum Name: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case london
    case liverpool
    case manchester
    case newcastle
    case norwich
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .london:
            return "London"
        case .liverpool:
            return "Liverpool"
        case .manchester:
            return "Manchester"
        case .newcastle:
            return "Newcastle"
        case .norwich:
            return "Norwich"
        }
    }
}
    
struct City: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: Name
    let info: String?
    var description: String {
        let info = self.info ?? "nil"
        return "City(name: \(self.name.description), info: \(info))"
    }
}


let cities = [
    City(name: .london, info:  "Emirates"),
    City(name: .liverpool, info:  "Anfield"),
    City(name: .manchester, info:  "Old Trafford"),
    City(name: .newcastle, info:  "St James Park"),
    City(name: .norwich, info:  "Carrow Road"),
]

let sortedCities = cities.sorted { $0.name.rawValue < $1.name.rawValue }

sortedCities.forEach {print($0)}
```

Comment: Correct, it isn't alphabetical but it is how the end user wants these to be displayed

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I created a dictionary containing sort indexes and sort by that.

Comment: Why don't you make your enumeration RawValue Int? This way you avoid having to create sort index and conform City to Comparable

Comment: Sure, but the OP's data has the enum raw values shown as strings. I took that to be a requirement. If it's not then this becomes a trivial problem.

Comment: Btw cases should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: I know that. I was cheating and having the name of the case be its raw value.

Comment: `enum Name: Int, CustomStringConvertible {` `case manchester, london, liverpool, newcastle, norwich` `var description: String {` `switch self {` `case .manchester: return "manchester"` `case .london: return "London"` `case .liverpool: return "Liverpool"` `case .newcastle: return "Newcastle"` `case .norwich: return "Norwich"` `}` `}` `}`

Comment: `struct City: CustomStringConvertible, Comparable {` `let name: Name` `let info: String?` `var description: String {` `"City(name: \(name), info: \(info ?? "nil"))"` `}` `static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {` `lhs.name.rawValue < rhs.name.rawValue` `}` `}`

Comment: Yup, that works, although it is awful to have to maintain the description switch statement for anything but a very short list of cases and little or no churn. I wish there was a "caseName" property on non-string enums that did the same thing rawValue does for String type enums.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to sort the entire array, but just ensure the order of specific elements at the top of the array, it might be best to just extract the  elements of interest and construct a new array with those elements at the top and with the rest left unchanged.

This way it has an O(n) complexity (assuming the custom sorting of the top is relatively small so can be assumed to be a constant), so for larger arrays it should be faster than doing the full array sorting.

The general approach would be:

```
let unsorted: [City] = ...

let topOrder = ["London", "Liverpool", "Manchester"]
var top: [String: City] = [:]
var rest: [City] = []

for city in unsorted {
   if topCorder.contains(city.name) {
      top[city.name] = city
   } else {
      rest.append(city)
   }
}

let sorted = topOrder.compactMap{ top[$0] } + rest
```

This doesn't handle the case of duplicates (it will drop them), but does handle the case of missing top cities.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable can be automatically synthesized for CaseIterable as of Swift 5.3.

```swift
import Foundation

struct City {
  enum Name: CaseIterable, Comparable {
    case london
    case liverpool
    case manchester
    case newcastle
    case norwich
  }

  let name: Name
}

extension City.Name: RawRepresentable {
  init?(rawValue: String) {
    guard let name = ( Self.allCases.first { $0.rawValue == rawValue } )
    else { return nil }

    self = name
  }

  var rawValue: String { "\(self)".capitalized }
}
```

```swift
AnyIterator { }
  .prefix(5)
  .map { City.Name.allCases.randomElement()! }
  .map(City.init)
  .sorted(\.name)
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted(comparable, <)
  }

  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value, and sorting closure.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ areInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted {
      try areInIncreasingOrder(comparable($0), comparable($1))
    }
  }
}
```